# How to split item in itemize over two lines

Tags: itemize

I have to use the document set up with the packages shown because this is dictated by the journal.

I simply want to prevent the item shown below from disappearing off the right hand side of the page. The most obvious solution would be to split it over two lines.

```
%The following LaTeX file is an example of an acceptable paper for the 
%Communications in Statistics.

%cisform.tex
%
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[tableposition = top]{caption}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}



\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.5in}
\def\refhg{\hangindent=20pt\hangafter=1}
\def\refmark{\par\vskip 2mm\noindent\refhg}
\def\refhg{\hangindent=20pt\hangafter=1}
\def\refmark{\par\vskip 2mm\noindent\refhg}
\def\refhg{\hangindent=20pt\hangafter=1}    %20pt
\def\refhgb{\hangindent=10pt\hangafter=1}
\def\refmark{\par\vskip 2mm\noindent\refhg}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\newcommand*\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\setlength\tabcolsep{5.69pt} % distance between columns in table


\begin{document}


\begin{itemize}
    \item  Simulate the X variables using eqn.1 with the following $(\rho_1,\rho_2)=(0.99,0.99),(0.99,0.1),(0.9,0.9),(0.9,0.1),(0.7,0.3)$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Two ways, `\\` and `parbox`.

The default `\parbox` command centers the box, and thus the bullet point, but by specifying `[t]` like `\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{<content>}` the box is aligned according to the top line and the bullet point works properly.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[tableposition = top]{caption}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}



\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.5in}
\def\refhg{\hangindent=20pt\hangafter=1}
\def\refmark{\par\vskip 2mm\noindent\refhg}
\def\refhg{\hangindent=20pt\hangafter=1}
\def\refmark{\par\vskip 2mm\noindent\refhg}
\def\refhg{\hangindent=20pt\hangafter=1}    %20pt
\def\refhgb{\hangindent=10pt\hangafter=1}
\def\refmark{\par\vskip 2mm\noindent\refhg}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\newcommand*\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\setlength\tabcolsep{5.69pt} % distance between columns in table


\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    % you could use a simple \\ to manually break the line
    \item  Simulate the X variables using eqn.1 with the following \\$(\rho_1,\rho_2)=(0.99,0.99),(0.99,0.1),(0.9,0.9),(0.9,0.1),(0.7,0.3)$
    % or use a top-aligned parbox set to the linewidth to wrap it automatically
    \item \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{Simulate the X variables using eqn.1 with the following $(\rho_1,\rho_2)=(0.99,0.99),$ $(0.99,0.1),$ $(0.9,0.9),$ $(0.9,0.1),$ $(0.7,0.3)$}
    % I broke the long equation into smaller equations to make text-wrapping work right. 
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can it be used to insert a picture or table between the splitted list?

Answer (score 2):

Just split the thing into several formulas:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Simulate the $X$ variables using equation~\ref{whatever} with the following
$(\rho_1,\rho_2)=(0.99,0.99)$, $(0.99,0.1)$, $(0.9,0.9)$, $(0.9,0.1)$, $(0.7,0.3)$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would make math into a displayed equation

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item  Simulate the X variables using eqn.1 with the following 
           \[(\rho_1,\rho_2)=(0.99,0.99),(0.99,0.1),(0.9,0.9),(0.9,0.1),(0.7,0.3)\]
\end{itemize}
```